# Fail to read locale using text/message and gotext, possibly importing other go file incorrectly

Tags: go

I wanted to learn how to do l10n in Go and came across this one website.  Google said it was 5 days old which confused me as it looks like it was written in 2018.  For reference the website is: https://phrase.com/blog/posts/internationalization-i18n-go/ and is focused on the content about 3/4 of the way through. I was reading some comments and it seems others had issues but didn't understand how to solve them if possible.

I am currently using: *Go version go1.16.3 darwin/amd64*

So, I found something which is great, using catalog to generate the l10n files I need, and then adding a new file which is referenced and then you can run it.  This example is using Greek.

Step one, make sure I had gotext in my cli.  This was done with: `go get -u golang.org/x/text/cmd/gotext`

Afterwards I created an empty go.mod file, and a main.go file  The main.go file contained the following information:

```
package main

//go:generate gotext -srclang=en update -out=catalog/catalog.go -lang=en,el

import (
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
    "golang.org/x/text/message"
    _ "golang.org/x/text/message/catalog"
)

func main() {
    p := message.NewPrinter(language.Greek)
    p.Println(language.Greek.String())
    p.Printf("Hello world!")
    p.Println()

    p.Printf("Hello", "world!")
    p.Println()

    person := "Alex"
    place := "Utah"

    p.Printf("Hello ", person, " in ", place, "!")
    p.Println()

    // Greet everyone.
    p.Printf("Hello world!")
    p.Println()

    city := "Munich"
    p.Printf("Hello %s!", city)
    p.Println()

    // Person visiting a place.
    p.Printf("%s is visiting %s!",
        person,
        place)
    p.Println()

    // Double arguments.
    miles := 1.2345
    p.Printf("%.2[1]f miles traveled (%[1]f)", miles)
}
```

and then did `mkdir catalog` and then `go generate`.  When you follow the how-to you will see that locale is created with the subfolders needed for localization. I created a second file in the *el* directory, called `messages.gotext.json` which I thought was weird because there is already a file in there called `out.gotext.json` so why the heck are there redundant files, beats me.  I figure there would really just be 1 file in there, the localization file which was translated.

Anyway, following the how-to, I created this second file, then ran the same code previously told: `go generate && go run main.go`.  Seems like it still prints in English, and I thought I was doing everything correct.

I thought I was doing this correctly but I see what the issue is.  What I am thinking is going on is that the generated catalog file is not being properly referenced in my import.  generate is creating this catalog.go file, but I don't think that the file is being properly added to my main.go file. Is that the case?

Am i importing this Catalog file correctly?

It seems that the Author has no idea what he was doing and his answers to the comment questions verify that he doesnt know how his own code/how-to works.  So that is why I wanted to come to you all, to see if there is something to be done which can generate the catalog file I need and import it.

Comment: "but i dont think that the file is being properly added to my main.go file? Am i importing this Catalog file correctly?" No. 1. You simply cannot import _files_. Imports happen on a per-package base. (Basically everything in Go is package based, so **please** stop using go run with filename arguments. A simple `go run .` is _much_ safer!) 2. If you want to import a package from your module you must do `import "<yourmodulename>/catalog"` in your main file.

Comment: BUT: The catalog.go file should be part of your main package (not some other package), so try `go:generate gotext -srclang=en update -out=catalog_gen.go -lang=en,el` and make sure you do provide the relevant translations in the local files.

Comment: Ah, ok. so that was the issue!  Thanks @Volker.  The output location seemed to resolve everything with regards to doing stuff.   After your adjustment, I did a `go generate && go run .` and bam, it works.